# Facebook blocked, show alternative content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, block

I run a bunch of websites in Vietnam, such as www.nyc.vn about New York City. The problem I have is that Facebook is blocked in Vietnam and that both the fan-box and like-buttons are shown as broken links in iframes "Page could not be found" when a blocked user views it.

I know that around 30% of visitors have a way around the block and thus want to give them the opportunity to like etc., but I would like to show the other 70% something else.

Is this possible somehow?

Cheers,

Anders

Comment: This should be possible to do somehow by making a defined JavaScript request to Facebook from the client (Like a JSONP request, an image...) and seeing whether it fails. Maybe embedding an image with a  defined URL (like the FB logo) and adding an `onerror` event to that that hides all the iframes? Can't play around with this out right now but maybe somebody else wants to.

Comment: Pekka, this seems very interesting. It is about out of my league when it comes to programming though, so if anyone has a link or a snippet that can help, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 2):

If you use button-images from facebooks cdn you can observe the onerror-event of these images and if it fires replace the surrounding link with something else(hope it fires, I don't know how they block it in vietnam)

Comment: `onerror` will fire if the server returns a `4xx` or a `5xx` in response to the image request.